# Java swap invalid

Tags: java, selection-sort

I'm working on a method aimed at sorting an array in ascending order. 
The array consists of earthquake marker objects, and what I need to do is sorting the array by the "magnitude" property of the objects. I tried selection sort but it seems that the elements aren't swapped properly.

Here is my code:

```
private void sortAndPrint(int numToPrint){
    Object[] quakeArray= quakeMarkers.toArray();

    int indexMax;
    for(int i=0; i<quakeArray.length-1; i++) {
        indexMax = i;
        float max = ((EarthquakeMarker)(quakeArray[i])).getMagnitude();

        for( int j =i+1; j<quakeArray.length;j++){
            if(((EarthquakeMarker)(quakeArray[j])).getMagnitude()>max)
                indexMax = j;
        }
        //swap it
        Object temp = quakeArray[i];
        quakeArray[i] = quakeArray[indexMax];
        quakeArray[indexMax] = temp;
    }
    //sort finished

    for(int i =0; i< numToPrint; i++) {
        System.out.println(((EarthquakeMarker)quakeArray[i]).getProperty("title").toString());
    }
}
```

It turned out that the quakes aren't sorted by their magnitude.

[image: console output]

From my perspective, there might be something wrong with the swap because Java is passing by value. If so, how can I fix it? Or does the problem lay somewhere else?

Comment: You're not updating your `max`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selection sort logic is incorrect. You never set max when you detected a new higher-valued entry. You probably want to either update max whenever you update indexMax, or to remove max and just use indexMax instead.

For a more practical approach, in most cases you probably should use built-in functionalities when they're available such as Array.sort().

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using Java's bult in Arrays.sort and passing a lambda function that compares the earthquake magnitudes.

Edit: Integer.compare can be used for comparison.

```
Arrays.sort( (a, b) -> Integer.compare( a.magnitude, b.magnitude) );
```

Comment: Or `Integer.compare(a.magnitude, b.magnitude)` instead of `a.magnitude - b.magnitude`.

Comment: Good point, thanks! That's something I've forgotten quite frequently.